# How can draw table in two column page in research articles?

Tags: tables, two-column, ieeetran

I want to draw tables in two column page, in landscape mode, as shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: The link to the image you posted is anything but self-explanatory. Which document class do you employ? How should landscape mode be entered? How wide are the page margins? The table on the right overflows into the bottom margin -- is that really what you want?

Comment: IEEE tran class is used.

Comment: Please provide MWE, which reproduce your problem. BTW, I observe that so far you not accept any of received answers. Did no one solve your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting objective requires incurring a bit of overhead. The code shown below, hopefully, provides the explanations needed to understand the LaTeX code.

It's *your* responsibility to assure that the two tables actually fit within the allocated space. If one of the tables is noticeably wider than the other, you may want to adjust the relative widths of the two `minipage` environments -- as long as the combined width of the tables is less than `\textwidth`.

The following screenshot shows the first two pages of the test document. (The third page contains more filler text.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math fonts

%% required packages:
\usepackage{rotating}  % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{afterpage} % for '\afterpage' macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{lipsum}    % filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6] % start with some filler text (all on page 1)

\afterpage{% defer execution till start of next page
   \clearpage % force-flush any accumulated floats
   
    \onecolumn % switch to one-column mode
    
    \begin{sidewaystable} % switch to landscape mode
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Parameter settings}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc} % a sample 'tabular' env.
    \toprule
    a & b & c \\
    \midrule 
    d & e & f \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}% % no empty line after this line
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{The success rate of x, y, and z}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{cccc} % another sample 'tabular' env.
    \toprule
    a & b & c & d \\
    \midrule 
    e & f & g & h \\
    i & j & k & l \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \end{sidewaystable} 
    
    \clearpage
    \twocolumn % revert to two-column mode
} % end of argument of \afterpage

\lipsum[7-20] % more filler text, to be typeset on pages 1 and 3 of sample doc.

\end{document}
```